# Scala Null for Double (Min Comparison for Aggregate)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So I have a function called AggregateByKey,

```
val initialValue:(Double, Double,Double,Double,Double) = (0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

I have a component of the AggregateByKey that does a min: math.min(u._4,v) 
The problem is that the initial value is 0.0 so if there are no negative numbers it always is 0.0 because its comparing the incoming number to 0.0. 
I've also tried to null.asInstanceOf[Double] but that also does not work. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to solve for this?

Comment: `AnyVal` types cannot be `null`. Why would you *want* to use `null`?

Comment: I need to use some value as the initial value to the aggregate by key but it will not work with Min.

Comment: I find your question really hard to understand, but below is my attempt at answering it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this istead of 0.0:

```
Double.PositiveInfinity
```

Comment: Whats the difference between positive infinity and max value?

Comment: PositiveInfinity is bigger than MaxValue.